# get_current_session returns None

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session

I've been using [geasessions](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions) for a while, been working great. It's simple and fast.

But today I started a new project (GAE v1.3.7) and can't get it to work, `get_current_session()` just returns `None`

I've split the code in to a new project that's just using gaesessions:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from gaesessions import get_current_session
import logging

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        session = get_current_session()
        logging.info(session)
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, { }))
```

And in the log it just says `None`.

The strange part is that the other solutions it still works. (I'm guessing it's due to that the db.Model for Session is already present). Tested both the version I use there and downloaded the latest version (1.04)

I've looked at the [source code](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions/blob/master/gaesessions/__init__.py) for gaesessions and it kinda make sense that it returns None:

```
_current_session = None
def get_current_session():
    """Returns the session associated with the current request."""
    return _current_session
```

And I can't find anywhere where the Session class is invoked, but then again it could be my laking python skills.

Does anyone use gaesession and know what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have missed something in the [installation process](http://github.com/dound/gae-sessions).

Anyway, if you scroll down the source code you will notice also this part of code that actually valorize the `_current_session` variable.

```
def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        # initialize a session for the current user
        global _current_session
        _current_session = Session(lifetime=self.lifetime, no_datastore=self.no_datastore, cookie_only_threshold=self.cookie_only_thresh, cookie_key=self.cookie_key)
```

Comment: You are absolutely right forgot to add SessionMiddleware in appengine_config!